# Web Consistency Testing & Selenium : is there any tool which we can integrate with selenium to perform Web consistency testing

Tags: selenium

Web Consistency Testing & Selenium : is there any tool which we can integrate with selenium to perform Web consistency testing

I can do this using Selenium but its scope is limited using getallButtons, getAllFields etc. but it does not fetch all Page elements and also it only fetches only buttons or labels not every GUI element which are actually causing problems

So is there any Web consistency tool which can(prefered) or can not be integrated with selenium?

Also please suggest any others ways you know to perform this without selenium or with selenium

Answer (score 3):

We built [our Web Consistency Testing service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6fV-6eMSUM) on top of Selenium and provide an API for integrating it into your Selenium testing suite.  I assume you're looking to build your own rather than use a third party.  In that case, there's really two parts that complementary to Selenium that you'll need to deal with: getting the DOM values and getting the screenshots for visualization.

Since Selenium can execute JavaScript in the browser for you and JavaScript has a DOM bridge, you can serialize your DOM that way.  You may find this too slow on IE, in which case you'll probably want to write some plugin to do it for you.  There was some discussion of this on the  [Web Consistency Testing mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/web-consistency-testing/browse_thread/thread/87190693d432c4cd).

For the screenshots, you almost certainly want the full canvas ones.  Selenium provides this for Firefox out of the box.  If you use the WebDriver protocol, you also get it in IE out of the box.  If you use the RC protocol, you'll need to check out [SnapsIE](https://github.com/nirvdrum/SnapsIE) to get the capability for IE.  We're pushing on the Chrome team to add something to their API to make support for this out of the box much easier -- until then, you likely would need to produce your own NPAPI-based plugin.

Answer (score 0):

u can use selenium to verify the functionality of your app. checking links and logics etc.. But css validation is not possible with selenium. u can use any of the open source  tool. i use browser shots. its simple and has a wide range of browsers. on the other hand drawbacks are also there its slow and u have keep increasing the time.
check out the links bellow. it may help you out.
http://browsershots.org/
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/07/a-dozen-cross-browser-testing-tools/

Comment: Thanks but i want to run scan on my Localhost which browsershots is unable to perform

Comment: u can check out selenium grid. it can run multiple browsers simultaneously. what u mentioned is a limitation of browsershots. in that case u will need to use some tool which can run the test on your local system. but most of these tools are paid.